# ServiceStack Razor cshtml pages not served on development machine

Tags: servicestack, iis-express

I'm seeing inconsistent results when working on ServiceStack Razor projects. The problem is that some projects begin to fail to serve cshtml pages in my development environment (Win 8, VS 2012). Using IIS Express in debug the home page (default.cshtml) returns:

```
Forbidden

Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo:
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /default.cshtml
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Users\jim\Documents\Visual Studio > 2012\Projects\Test.Web\Test.Web
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [about.cshtml,apphost.cs,default.cshtml,global.asax,global.asax.cs,packages.config,pricing.cshtml,privacy.cshtml,reconcilable.web.csproj,test.web.csproj.user,terms.cshtml,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,bin,obj,properties,public,services,views]
App.DefaultRootFileName: default.cshtml
```

If I request the page on a different URL I see the following:

```
Handler for Request not found: 

Request.ApplicationPath: /
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath: /terms
Request.FilePath: /terms
Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.MapPath('~'): C:\Users\jim\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test.Web\Test.Web\
Request.Path: /terms
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.ResolvedPathInfo: /terms
Request.PhysicalPath: C:\Users\jim\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test.Web\Test.Web\terms
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath: C:\Users\jim\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test.Web\Test.Web\
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /terms
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri: http://localhost:51000/terms
Request.Url.AbsolutePath: /terms
Request.Url.Fragment: 
Request.Url.Host: localhost
Request.Url.LocalPath: /terms
Request.Url.Port: 51000
Request.Url.Query: 
Request.Url.Scheme: http
Request.Url.Segments: System.String[]
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\Users\jim\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test.Web\Reconcilable.Web
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [about.cshtml,apphost.cs,default.cshtml,global.asax,global.asax.cs,packages.config,test.web.csproj,test.web.csproj.user,terms.cshtml,web.config,web.debug.config,web.release.config,bin,obj,properties,public,services,views]
App.DefaultRootFileName: default.cshtml
App.DefaultHandler: default.cshtml
App.DebugLastHandlerArgs: GET|/terms|C:\Users\jim\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test.Web\Test.Web\terms
```

I can create a clean new project that serves pages correctly, but an older project with identical web.config, AppHost, Global.asax files fails. Code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>

public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }

}

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("test", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
    }
}
```

I don't see the same problem when the project is deployed to the server. Is anyone able to give me some ideas of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I think this problem is specific to my development machine. When I debug the site on my home PC there is no problem. My conclusion is that my dev machine has a configuration that is causing this problem. I think I'll need to look at the machine rather than the code to try to resolve this.

Comment: I got the same problem; did you find out what the problem is/was?

Comment: Me too, any solution?

Comment: There is one work around. Change your cshtml file property to copy if newer and check if it is working. It is wrong but may be that will help.

Comment: Exactly the same ! driving me crazy ! new projects no problem, current one : no .cshtml served in any way :/.. removed everything, changed the whole web.config...IIS really is an obscure beast...